Swift package/Xcode; skipping cache due to an error
I am getting the following error when attempting to update package caches, as a result of which I cannot build:
skipping cache due to an error: git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git: An unknown error occurred. reference 'refs/remotes/origin/main' not found (-1)
I have quit Xcode and deleted derived data, but it hasn't helped.
Local git operations work fine.
I cannot use https because I am accessing private repos.
Any insights appreciated

I get the same error for some time now. Using a private repo with https url.
